# jquery ValidationEngine prompts start in incorrect position and animate to new position

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

I'm having an issue where my error prompts show up at a certain position, then animate to a new position (margin-top changes). It's as if the initial position of the error prompt is incorrect (buildPrompt method), then the updatePrompt method executes and animates the prompt to the new position.

I can't figure out why the prompts don't calculatePosition properly the first time...

Answer (score 1):

It happans because when you try to validate it gets attached to elements at that particular moment. To avoid this you wil have to attach all input/select fields (or only desired ones) on yout page load or ready function. For eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input,select').validationEngine('attach');
})
```

Hope it solves your problem, it solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

make a div where the prompt should be displayed, if possible inside a table

```
<div id="prompt"></div>
```

and then

```
$("#prompt").validationEngine('showPrompt', 'message', 'red', 'topRight', true);
```